# XML output from XML and XSL input consists of all data consolidated into one record

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I have created a XSL file and have a report creating XML input which i have to transform into another type of XML (Output).

XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Generated by EnterpriseOne Universal Batch Engine-->
<R570018A>
<Properties>
<Version>LU0001</Version>
<Title>Luxembourg VAT return</Title>
<Machine>PCOJDEDEV04</Machine>
<Environment>DV920</Environment>
<User>ASDF</User>
<Role>*ALL</Role>
<Company>XYZ.LP</Company>
<OneWorldRelease>E920</OneWorldRelease>
<Date>10/29/2019</Date>
<Time>13:58:13</Time>
</Properties>
<PageHeaders>
<Page_Header_S2>
<PageHeaderNumber>1</PageHeaderNumber>
<R570018A_ID1>R570018A</R570018A_ID1>
<Variable_000002_ID2>XYZ.LP</Variable_000002_ID2>
<Variable_000005_ID5>13:58:13</Variable_000005_ID5>
<Variable_000004_ID4>2019-10-29</Variable_000004_ID4>
<Variable_000003_ID3>Luxembourg VAT return</Variable_000003_ID3>
<Variable_000006_ID6>1</Variable_000006_ID6>
<of_ID7>of</of_ID7>
<Page___ID9>Page -</Page___ID9>
</Page_Header_S2>
</PageHeaders>
-<Report_Header_S5>
<AgentMatrNbr_ID2>54564646</AgentMatrNbr_ID2>
<DeclarerMatrNbr_ID7>9879862</DeclarerMatrNbr_ID7>
<Year_PO_ID11>2019</Year_PO_ID11>
<AgentRCSNbr_ID4>5362189</AgentRCSNbr_ID4>
<DeclarerRCSNbr_ID8>8795462525</DeclarerRCSNbr_ID8>
<Period_Number_PO_ID13>10</Period_Number_PO_ID13>
<AgentVATNbr_ID6>988765142</AgentVATNbr_ID6>
<DeclarerVATNbr_ID9>98795668</DeclarerVATNbr_ID9>
</Report_Header_S5>
<UDC___Full_View_of_F0005_for_Transfer_57_LV_Driver_S1>
<Vat_Cross_Ref_57_LV_Print_S3>

<Print_F570018A_S6>
<PageHeaderNumber>1</PageHeaderNumber>
<AccountNumber_ID1>472</AccountNumber_ID1>
<Amount_57LV_ID2>-65071.80</Amount_57LV_ID2>
</Print_F570018A_S6>
<Print_F570018A_S6>
<PageHeaderNumber>1</PageHeaderNumber>
<AccountNumber_ID1>019</AccountNumber_ID1>
<Amount_57LV_ID2>-65071.80</Amount_57LV_ID2>

</Print_F570018A_S6>
<Print_F570018A_S6>
<PageHeaderNumber>1</PageHeaderNumber>
<AccountNumber_ID1>741</AccountNumber_ID1>
<Amount_57LV_ID2>5128.21</Amount_57LV_ID2>
</Print_F570018A_S6>
<Print_F570018A_S6>
<PageHeaderNumber>1</PageHeaderNumber>
<AccountNumber_ID1>742</AccountNumber_ID1>
<Amount_57LV_ID2>871.79</Amount_57LV_ID2>
</Print_F570018A_S6>

</Vat_Cross_Ref_57_LV_Print_S3>
</UDC___Full_View_of_F0005_for_Transfer_57_LV_Driver_S1>
</R570018A>
```

XSL input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <all xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
  <xsl:template match="/"><!-- Root template -->
 - <eCDFDeclarations xmlns="http://www.ctie.etat.lu/2011/ecdf">
   <FileReference>"UMKBJLX20181003T17180101"</FileReference>
   <eCDFFileVersion>1.1</eCDFFileVersion>
   <Interface>CMUL8</Interface>
   -<Agent>
    <MatrNbr>
    <xsl:value-of select="/R570018A/Report_Header_S5/AgentMatrNbr_ID2"/>
    </MatrNbr>
    <RCSNbr>
    <xsl:value-of select="/R570018A/Report_Header_S5/AgentRCSNbr_ID4"/>
    </RCSNbr>
    <VATNbr>
    <xsl:value-of select="/R570018A/Report_Header_S5/AgentVATNbr_ID6"/>
    </VATNbr>
    </Agent>

    -<Declarations>

    -<Declarer>
     <MatrNbr>
     <xsl:value-of select="/R570018A/Report_Header_S5/DeclarerMatrNbr_ID7"/>
     </MatrNbr>
     <RCSNbr>
     <xsl:value-of select="/R570018A/Report_Header_S5/DeclarerRCSNbr_ID8"/>
     </RCSNbr>
     <VATNbr>
     <xsl:value-of select="/R570018A/Report_Header_S5/DeclarerVATNbr_ID9"/>
     </VATNbr>

     -<Declaration language="FR" model="1" type="TVA_DECM">
      <Year>
      <xsl:value-of select="/R570018A/Report_Header_S5/Year_PO_ID11"/>
      </Year>
      <Period>
      <xsl:value-of select="/R570018A/Report_Header_S5/Period_Number_PO_ID13"/>
      </Period>

      -<FormData>

        -<NumericField id="{/R570018A/UDC___Full_View_of_F0005_for_Transfer_57_LV_Driver_S1/Vat_Cross_Ref_57_LV_Print_S3/Print_F570018A_S6/AccountNumber_ID1}"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="/R570018A/UDC___Full_View_of_F0005_for_Transfer_57_LV_Driver_S1/Vat_Cross_Ref_57_LV_Print_S3/Print_F570018A_S6/Amount_57LV_ID2"/> 
        </NumericField>

       </FormData>
      </Declaration>
     </Declarer>
    </Declarations>


  </eCDFDeclarations>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Acquired output:

```
 - <eCDFDeclarations xmlns="http://www.ctie.etat.lu/2011/ecdf">
   <FileReference>"UMKBJLX20181003T17180101"</FileReference>
   <eCDFFileVersion>1.1</eCDFFileVersion>
   <Interface>CMUL8</Interface>
   -<Agent>
      <MatrNbr>54564646</MatrNbr>
      <RCSNbr>5362189</RCSNbr>
      <VATNbr>988765142</VATNbr>
   </Agent>

    -<Declarations>

    -<Declarer>
         <MatrNbr>9879862</MatrNbr>
         <RCSNbr>8795462525</RCSNbr>
         <VATNbr>98795668</VATNbr>

     -<Declaration language="FR" model="1" type="TVA_DECM">
            <Year>2019</Year>
            <Period>10</Period>

      -<FormData>

        -<NumericField id="472 019 741 742">-65071.80 -65071.80 5128.21 871.79</NumericField>
            </FormData>
         </Declaration>
      </Declarer>
   </Declarations>
</eCDFDeclarations>
```

expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<eCDFDeclarations xmlns="http://www.ctie.etat.lu/2011/ecdf">
  <FileReference>UMKBJLX20181003T17180101</FileReference>
  <eCDFFileVersion>1.1</eCDFFileVersion>
  <Interface>CMUL8</Interface>
  <Agent>
    <MatrNbr>54564646</MatrNbr>
    <RCSNbr>5362189</RCSNbr>
    <VATNbr>988765142</VATNbr>
  </Agent>
  <Declarations>
    <Declarer>
      <MatrNbr>9879862</MatrNbr>
      <RCSNbr>8795462525</RCSNbr>
      <VATNbr>98795668</VATNbr>

      <Declaration language="FR" model="1" type="TVA_DECM">
        <Year>2019</Year>
        <Period>10</Period>
        <FormData>
          <NumericField id="472">-65071,80</NumericField>
          <NumericField id="019">-65071,80</NumericField>
          <NumericField id="741">5128,21</NumericField>
          <NumericField id="742">871,79</NumericField>

 </FormData>
      </Declaration>
    </Declarer>
  </Declarations>
</eCDFDeclarations>
```

My issue is that all the Numeric field ID and amounts print in the same line instead of going to next line.
I'm quite new to using XSL inputs could you please let me know how I should edit my XSL input file?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example, not code snippets - see: [mcve].

Comment: Edited the snippets to include the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following XSLT. I added the `xsl:output` element at the top to produce a prolog and a loop for repeating values in the fragment in question.

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <all xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- Root template -->
        <eCDFDeclarations xmlns="http://www.ctie.etat.lu/2011/ecdf">
            <FileReference>"UMKBJLX20181003T17180101"</FileReference>
            <eCDFFileVersion>1.1</eCDFFileVersion>
            <Interface>CMUL8</Interface>
            <Agent>
                <MatrNbr>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/R570018A/Report_Header_S5/AgentMatrNbr_ID2"/>
                </MatrNbr>
                <RCSNbr>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/R570018A/Report_Header_S5/AgentRCSNbr_ID4"/>
                </RCSNbr>
                <VATNbr>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/R570018A/Report_Header_S5/AgentVATNbr_ID6"/>
                </VATNbr>
            </Agent>

            <Declarations>

                <Declarer>
                    <MatrNbr>
                        <xsl:value-of select="/R570018A/Report_Header_S5/DeclarerMatrNbr_ID7"/>
                    </MatrNbr>
                    <RCSNbr>
                        <xsl:value-of select="/R570018A/Report_Header_S5/DeclarerRCSNbr_ID8"/>
                    </RCSNbr>
                    <VATNbr>
                        <xsl:value-of select="/R570018A/Report_Header_S5/DeclarerVATNbr_ID9"/>
                    </VATNbr>

                    <Declaration language="FR" model="1" type="TVA_DECM">
                        <Year>
                            <xsl:value-of select="/R570018A/Report_Header_S5/Year_PO_ID11"/>
                        </Year>
                        <Period>
                            <xsl:value-of select="/R570018A/Report_Header_S5/Period_Number_PO_ID13"/>
                        </Period>

                        <FormData>
                            <xsl:for-each select="R570018A/UDC___Full_View_of_F0005_for_Transfer_57_LV_Driver_S1/Vat_Cross_Ref_57_LV_Print_S3/Print_F570018A_S6">
                                <NumericField id="{AccountNumber_ID1}">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Amount_57LV_ID2"/>
                                </NumericField>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </FormData>
                    </Declaration>
                </Declarer>
            </Declarations>
        </eCDFDeclarations>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```